# Inductive proposition for sublists in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, inductive-logic-programming

I am struggling with coming up with a notion of sublist of a list, which is created by deleting elements in the list (so that the order is preserved). I need to come up with an inductive proposition that decides if l1 is a sublist of l2.

So far:

1. I know the empty list is a sublist of all lists.
2. All lists are sublists of themselves.
3. If it is known that l1 is a sublist of l2, then lists resulting from appending the same list to both l1 and l2 at the head or tail would result in the former being a sublist of the latter
4. Now is the hard part. How to provide evidence that a list like ["x";"y"] is a sublist of ["a";"x";"z";"y"]?

The syntax is something like
Inductive Sublist {X : Type} : list X -> list X -> Prop := ..

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you do informally already? Using just your three rules. If you can't manage it means that you have perhaps a too complicated / incomplete definition.

I think instead of trying to think of all those complicated examples you could focus on your example(s) while keeping in mind how lists are constructed.
Why is `[ x ; y ]` a sublist of `[ a ; x ; y ; z ]`? Because (without the head of the second list) `[ x ; y ]` is a sublist of `[ x ; y ; z ]`, and that's because `[ y ]` is a sublist of `[ y ; z ]`, which is because `[]` is a sublist of `[ z ]` which always holds.

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: I actually got it. I needed only three rules, the ones mentioned :). Also skip the tail parts altogether